# Webpack && npm, how can I create a script that can both be imported by another webpack project, or included as a script tag?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Let's say I'm using webpack 4 and have a project that looks like this:

`/src/index.js`

```
const Important = "Important Text"
export default Important
global.important = Important
```

I compile it using the following webpack confing:

```
output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
},
module: {
    rules: [
        { ...babelConfig }
    ]
}
```

And the `package.json` has:

```
{
    ...packageJsonContents
    "name": "important-project",
    "main": "./dist/main.js",
}
```

This will create the minified file `/dist/main.js`
I save that plugin to npm as `testproject`

---

Now I create another project, configure Webpack and `npm install important-project`.

In the `/src/index.js`:

```
import Important from 'important-project'

console.log(Important) //prints "Important Text"
```

This works, however my goal is for this to be a general use plugin and I want to also be able to include it as a script tag in other projects, however when I include it as a script tag, it complains that module is not defined.

```
<script src="node_modules/important-project/dist/main.js"></script>
```

What's the conventional approach here? Should I create two builds? One for in html, and another for in webpack?

Comment: Webpack has a configuration "output.library" that will put your module in global scope with the supplied name: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library I use this to integrate my ES6 code into a legacy app via including the webpack-generated bundle in a `<script>` tag. Does this do what you want?

Comment: @MattHolland, I tried adding `library: 'global'` to the `output` config in the above example and it's still erroring out on `module` and `Important` not being defined in the script tag. I changed the `libraryTarget` to `umd` and it won't build in a webpack project, complaining that `window` is not defined

Comment: Looks like it works inside of webpack in a browser environment, and in a script tag in a browser environment - but not in webpack + node.

Comment: Does your module's code rely on `window` at all?